# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc, using hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, input-encodings

I have a class file in my `LaTeX` project. When I include the package `\usepackage{hyperref}` I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.
```

The cls file:

```
% http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/doc/clsguide.pdf
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SCmastersthesis}[2021/11/30 SC Master''s Thesis class]

\LoadClass[12pt, a4paper, openright]{report}

% Usefull packages
\usepackage[arabic, french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\RequirePackage{microtype}   % Improves typography
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tabto}       % Tabulation
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize} % size of fonts
% For all sorts of hyperlinks in the PDF output.

% Commands for title, readers, authors, dates, specialities,...
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\def\@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\secondauthor}[1]{\def\@secondauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\thirdauthor}[1]{\def\@thirdauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\def\@supervisor{#1}}
\newcommand{\secondsupervisor}[1]{\def\@secondsupervisor{#1}}
\newcommand{\thirdsupervisor}[1]{\def\@thirdsupervisor{#1}}
\newcommand{\degreetitle}[1]{\def\@degreetitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\options}[1]{\def\@myoptions{#1}}
\newcommand{\readerone}[1]{\def\@readerone{#1}}
\newcommand{\readertwo}[1]{\def\@readertwo{#1}}
\newcommand{\readerthree}[1]{\def\@readerthree{#1}}
\newcommand{\readerfour}[1]{\def\@readerfour{#1}}
\newcommand{\readerfive}[1]{\def\@readerfive{#1}}
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\def\@years{#1}}

% Lenghts
\newlength{\tabAuthor}
\newlength{\tabSupervisor}
\newlength{\tabReader}

% Title creation
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm}
    
    % background
    \noindent \hspace{-3cm} 
    \includegraphics{_frontbanner_SC-master-thesis_3.pdf}\\
    \vspace*{-\textheight}
    
    % Font
    \color{white} \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont
    
    % Define lengths
    \setlength{\tabAuthor}{
        \ifdef{\@secondauthor}{1.7cm}{1.6cm}
    }
    \setlength{\tabSupervisor}{
        \ifdef{\@secondsupervisor}{2.55cm}{2.45cm}
    }
    \setlength{\tabReader}{
        \ifdef{\@readertwo}{1.9cm}{1.8cm}
    }    
    
    \vspace*{9cm}
    
    % Title and subtitle
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][c]{1\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    %\vspace*{2cm}
    {
      \fontsize{26}{36}\selectfont \textbf{\@title}
      
      \vspace*{12pt}
      
      \ifdef{\@subtitle}{\fontsize{20}{30} \selectfont \@subtitle}{$ $} \\
    } 
    \end{minipage}
    
    
    % Metadata
    \vspace*{4cm}
    \noindent \hspace{1.7cm}
    \begin{minipage}[l]{.85\textwidth}
      % authors
      \ifdef{\@secondauthor}{Auteurs:}{Auteur:}{\bfseries
        \tabto{\tabAuthor}\@author
        \ifdef{\@secondauthor}{, \@secondauthor}{}
        \ifdef{\@thirdauthor}{, \@thirdauthor}{}}
      \\
      % supervisors
      \ifdef{\@secondsupervisor}{Promoteurs:}{Promoteur:}{\bfseries
        \tabto{\tabSupervisor}\@supervisor
        \ifdef{\@secondsupervisor}{, \@secondsupervisor}{}\ifdef{\@thirdsupervisor}{, \@thirdsupervisor}{}}
      \\
      % readers
      \ifdef{\@readertwo}{Lecteurs:}{Lecteur:}{\bfseries
        \tabto{\tabReader}\@readerone
        \ifdef{\@readertwo}{, \@readertwo}{}\ifdef{\@readerthree}{, \@readerthree}{}\ifdef{\@readerfour}{, \@readerfour}{}\ifdef{\@readerfive}{, \@readerfive}{}}
      \\
      % academic year
      Année académique \@years
      \\
      % degree title
      \@degreetitle      
    \end{minipage}
  \end{titlepage}
}

% Front cover page
\newcommand{\frontpage}
{
  \begin{titlepage}
  \end{titlepage}
}

% Back cover page
\newcommand{\backcoverpage}
{
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newgeometry{top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm}
  \includegraphics{_backbanner_SC-master-thesis.pdf}

}

\endinput
```

Comment: what do you intend `\usepackage[cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,utf8x]{inputenc}`  to do?? It can not do anythig useful,  a file can only be in one encoding at a time, and utf-8 is the default, so just delete the whole line.

Comment: Thank you , but that doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: But the problem occurs only when I add the instruction : ``\usepackage{hyperref}``

Comment: No it shows hyperref but only becuse that is on the following line, delete the inputec line and the error will go (I just tried your class)

Comment: your class already loads hyperref, so why are you trying to add hyperref again?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hyperrer is just loaded once

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed that they load it again in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a test file

```
\documentclass{SCmastersthesis}

\begin{document}

a
\end{document}
```

You get

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \usepackage
                [hidelinks]{hyperref}
?
```

But `hyperref` is not involved here, in fact the linebreak in the message shows `[hidelinks]{hyperref}` has not even been read yet.

The error is on the previous line

```
\usepackage[cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,cp1256,utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Which could never do anything useful, and can simply be deleted.  Without this line the example runs without error

Comment: hm, one get the clash because arabic loads inputenc with cp1256 so simply removing the line means that the document is read as cp1256. One should probably switch the encoding, but this could break arabic ...

Comment: I think one must load \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} *before* arabic, then it won't try to load it itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the class shouldn't be specifying the document encoding anyway

Comment: the problem is \usepackage[arabic]{babel} which will load inputenc. (arabic.ldf contains \@ifpackageloaded{inputenc}{}{\RequirePackage[cp1256]{inputenc}}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the class shouldn't be setting the document language either:-)

Comment: it shouldn't also set the pdftex driver ;-)